# How to change mesh(vertex) sequence dynamically on Sceneform android?

Tags: android, augmented-reality

There is an framework that allow to work with AR - Sceneform and there is a lot of examples how you can load just one fragment of your model.

[image]

Like you can see here, we can see just one static model.

What I actually need to do is - make this model move. Like here in example

https://youtu.be/BOrg2oc3-rQ?t=1003

It is also ar model but each frame you need to change the vertexes and textures and render them.

I found an example

https://medium.com/krootl/arcore-sceneform-simple-video-playback-3fe2f909bfbc

And eventually you can get something like this

https://vimeo.com/329962240

But here as you can see we changing each frame just a textures. Vertexes it is the same vertexes.

And I did not find any option how to change also vertex sequence.

So, if someone has such expiriance or have an idea how to do it, I appreciate. Or maybe I did not find anything about it because Sceneform doesn't support this?